# How can I share OS X fonts with Windows XP when using vmware-fusion?

Tags: windows, mac, vmware-fusion

When using VMware Fusion, is there any way to share fonts between the base OS (i.e., OS X) and the virtualized OS (e.g., Windows XP)?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to copy them to Windows's disk and add them to the Fonts folder in the Control Panel. There is no provision for "sharing" fonts.

Comment: Thank you CajonLuke.  I tried copying the font from the OS X font folder to the Windows font folder, but only the bold version of the font is visible on the Windows VM.

Comment: Is the font file just the one weight or is is a "suitcase" with multiple weights? How does Font Book on the Mac handle the font?

Comment: Font Book shows that it has [Regular, Italic, Bold, ExtraBlack, Bold Italic].  And when I look at the file name it has a `ttc` extension, where most of the other fonts in my library have a `ttf` extension or no extension at all.

Comment: It appears that Windows doesn't support .ttc font collections. I tried to move one to my Windows 7 VM and it claims that the file is invalid.